# React leaflet support react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, leaflet, react-leaflet

I recently migrated to react native and looking for an alternative to google maps I found the leaflet, but I didn't find any example to help me with mobile. Has anyone used the library on mobile?

Comment: First, you need to convert your leaflet html and render it as react web app. After that use react native components webview and target the uri  react web app that you created earlier.